# AFNetworking Couldn't Send JSONData through POST Request?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

This is the code I wrote for posting JSON to server.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *mgr = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
mgr.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
NSLog(@"Dictionary %@",formData);
[mgr POST:[self getFullURL:WSFormSubmit] parameters:formData success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

formData Prints as:

```
{
    FieldValueDTOs =     (
                          {
                          AdditionalInfo = "";
                          CreateTime = "2015-09-09 10:14";
                          FieldValue = "";
                          ReportFieldValueID = 0;
                          ReportID = 0;
                          ReportTemplateFieldID = 21642;
                          },
                          {
                          AdditionalInfo = "";
                          CreateTime = "2015-09-09 10:14";
                          FieldValue = asdfasdf;
                          ReportFieldValueID = 0;
                          ReportID = 0;
                          ReportTemplateFieldID = 21643;
                          }
                          );
    LocationID = 27;
    ReportID = 0;
    ReportLabel = "";
    ReportTemplateID = 930;
    ReportTime = "2015-09-09 10:14";
}
```

This seems to be perfect Dictionary to send it as a parameter to manager's POST:parameters:success method.

But it's returning this error when I do this. I couldn't figure out what's causing the error.

Error log in debugger:

```
Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x79069f90 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set., NSUnderlyingError=0x790517c0 "Request failed: bad request (400)"}
```

Comment: I have crossed check with Andorid app and the JSON data it's sending is same and it sends successfully. Could it be because the server is expecting JSON data in body instead of POST parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works, you can set values for json in header field

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *mgr = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

AFJSONRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

mgr.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;

[mgr POST:[self getFullURL:WSFormSubmit] parameters:formData success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

**formData** must be **NSDictionary** object

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:60];

    [manager POST:[self getFullURL:WSFormSubmit]
       parameters:formData
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                 NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                  NSLog(@"Response: %@",newStr);
          } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
              NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
          }];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];
[manager POST:"<Your Host URL>" parameters:<Params as Dictionary> success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    // *** Perform success action ***

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // *** perform failure action ***
}];
```

you forgot to set contentType for your request which is `JSON` and make sure your API accepts `JSON` and `POST` data as input otherwise it will not work.